# Best way to make VueJS components in a client side

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to use VueJS in a JAVA application. I've already made a big Vue component but now I want to divide this big component in little part...

How to declare components and use them in client side only way ?

Thanks for tips!

Comment: The question is too broad. Here's the docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Comment: Did u manage to do this? how did you include Vue.js and its components on server side java and rendered these components?

Comment: Well, we add VueJS for each page with a script tag. And we load all the components in a html page that we add at the end of the current page. Then we use a component. They are declared on each page load :/

Comment: Could you write that as an Answer to your own question, and add some sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I know a little bit more about VueJS, I found my question weird...

Well, we don't have any JS loader so we have to load the html files (with the Vue component declared) in the main html file to be able to use it.

```
html code...

// import html file with component
// import html file with component

// use component
```